# JavaScript click addEventListener not working on my code

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am trying to get a JavaScript listener to work but nothing changes.

Here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #trigger {
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: red;
      border: 1px solid white;
      width: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #box {
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: green;
      border: 1px solid white;
      width: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="trigger">Click Here</div>
  <div id="box">
    content should change
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("click", () => {
      document.getElementById("trigger"), () => {
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "New Box Text";
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can do this using jQuery, but I want to do it with just pure, vanilla JavaScript.

When I click on `#trigger`, `#box` text is not changing. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: you need something like `document.querySelector('#trigger').onclick`, but my point is that you should target an element.

Comment: @B.J.A.A. Using `addEventListener` is a better practice than `onclick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run your code only, when the [**DOM**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) completely loaded and parsed, add an evenet listener under the [**`DOMContentLoaded`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, then use [**querySelector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the element with the `#trigger` id, then add a `click` event listener to it and use `querySelector` again to select the element with `#box` id and modify its `.innerHTML` accordingly:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector("#trigger").addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector("#box").innerHTML = "New Box Text";
  });
});
```

The great thing about using [**querySelector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and also [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is that they provide a similar functionality compared to jQuery, when selecting elements.

**Example:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #trigger {
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: red;
      border: 1px solid white;
      width: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #box {
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: green;
      border: 1px solid white;
      width: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="trigger">Click Here</div>
  <div id="box">
    content should change
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      document.querySelector("#trigger").addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector("#box").innerHTML = "New Box Text";
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the listener to the box element rather than the entire page:

```js
document.getElementById("trigger").addEventListener("click", () =>
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "New Box Text"
);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #trigger {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        border:1px solid white;
        width: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #box {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: green;
        border:1px solid white;
        width: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="trigger">Click Here</div>
<div id="box">
    content should change
</div>

</body>
</html>
```